# Crear Customs Fields en Cart Page Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

estoy creando un plugin para insertar dos fields custom en el carrito de compras, es decir dos columnas con cada una un campo, uno para ingresar comentarios, y otro para un select, ambos sobre cada producto del carrito, querìa saber ya que estuve buscando bastante informaciòn y no pude lograrlo exitosamente si alguno ya tuvo que hacerlo, o sabe como hacerlo ! Muchas gracias por su aporte

Edito el post con parte del codigo que voy haciendo, el problema esta en que al actualizar la pagina los comentarios se borran, y cuando finalizo la compra no se guarda tampoco la información

Agrego a cada producto del carrito un campo para comentarios

```
function prefix_after_cart_item_name( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
  $notes = isset( $cart_item['notes'] ) ? $cart_item['notes'] : '';
  printf(
  '<td class="product-comment" data-title="Comentarios"><div><textarea class="%s" id="cart_notes_%s" data-cart-id="%s">%s</textarea></div></td>',
  'prefix-cart-notes',
  $cart_item_key,
  $cart_item_key,
  $notes
  );
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'prefix_after_cart_item_name', 10, 2 );
```

Hago un enqueue the archivo js para poder actualizar el valor del carrito al actualizarlo

```
function prefix_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'prefix-script', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . 'js/update-cart-item-ajax.js', array( 'jquery-blockui' ), time(), true );
  wp_localize_script(
  'prefix-script',
  'prefix_vars',
  array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
  )
  );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-script' );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Archivo JS que se encarga de actualizar el carrito

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.prefix-cart-notes').on('change keyup paste', function() {
            $('.cart_totals').block({
                message: null,
                overlayCSS: {
                    background: '#fff',
                    opacity: 0.6
                }
            });
            var cart_id = $(this).data('cart-id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: prefix_vars.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'prefix_update_cart_notes',
                    security: $('#woocommerce-cart-nonce').val(),
                    notes: $('#cart_notes_' + cart_id).val(),
                    cart_id: cart_id
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.cart_totals').unblock();
                }
            })
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Ese codigo lo tome de [aca](https://pluginrepublic.com/how-to-add-an-input-field-to-woocommerce-cart-items/) pero no me estaria funcionando !

Actualmente se ve asi el carrito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, ahi actualice el post con mas informacion